# Change text and replace button/text upon button clicks in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

What is the best way to approach this? I need two buttons to display two different messages if you click either one button. Then replace the button with another text when clicked. 
Is there any good Samaritan willing to help me out? I am new to javascript and only have come to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<div> Text 0 </div>
<input type="button" id="toggler" value="Toggler" onClick="action();" />
<input type="button" id="togglee" value="Togglee" />
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var hidden = false;
    function action() {
        hidden = !hidden;
        if(hidden) {
            document.getElementById('togglee').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('togglee').style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
    }

 function hideAll(){
     document.getElementById("id1").style.display="none";
     document.getElementById("id2").style.display="none";
     document.getElementById("id3").style.display="none";    
}
function show(elementId) { 
    hideAll();
    document.getElementById(elementId).style.display="block";
}
</script>
<div id="id1">text 1</div>
<div id="id2">text 2</div>
<div id="id3">text 3</div>

<button type="button" onclick="show('id1');">Choice 1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="show('id2');">Choice 2</button>
<button type="button" onclick="show('id3');">Choice 3</button>



<script type="text/javascript">
    hideAll();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: not clear what you're aiming for. please, try to explain more, maybe giving an example would help.

Comment: Please edit your question and add more info

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of changing button text when a button is clicked. You can easily target other things such as display by doing the same:

```js
const button1 = document.querySelector('#button1');
const button2 = document.querySelector('#button2');
const hideButtons = document.querySelector('#hideButtons');
const showButtons = document.querySelector('#showButtons');
let btn1Count = 0;
let btn2Count = 0;
button1.onclick = (evt) => {
 btn1Count++;
 button1.innerText = `Click Count ${btn1Count}`;
};

button2.onclick = (evt) => {
 btn2Count++;
 button2.innerText = `Click Count ${btn2Count}`;
};
hideButtons.onclick = () => {
 button1.style.display = 'none';
  button2.style.display = 'none';
}
showButtons.onclick = () => {
 button1.style.display = 'block';
  button2.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<button id="button1">
 Button 1
</button>
<button id="button2">
Button 2
</button>
<button id="hideButtons">
 Hide Buttons
 </button>
 <button id="showButtons">
 Show Buttons
 </button>
```